# How could two NSDates with same date value and same hash be unequal?

Tags: ios, comparison, nsdate

I stored an object under one `NSDate` key in an `NSDictionary`. I then got another `NSDate` with the same date value and used it to retrieve the object from the `NSDictionary`. To my surprise, it returned `nil`. But what was revealed during my debug session blew my mind even more:

> (lldb) po when
>   (NSDate *) $34 = 0x0f8be100 2012-05-11 21:08:37 +0000
>   (lldb) po [newTaskDict objectForKey:when]
>   (id) $36 = 0x00000000 
>   (lldb) po [newTaskDict allKeys]
>   (id) $37 = 0x0f8c1650 <__NSArrayI 0xf8c1650>(
>   2012-05-11 21:08:37 +0000
>   )
>   (lldb) po [[newTaskDict allKeys] lastObject]
>   (id) $38 = 0x0f8b5ff0 2012-05-11 21:08:37 +0000
>   (lldb) p (int)[[[newTaskDict allKeys] lastObject] isEqual:when]
>   (int) $39 = 0
>   (lldb) po [[[newTaskDict allKeys] lastObject] class]
>   (id) $40 = 0x3f4496b0 __NSDate
>   (lldb) po [when class]
>   (id) $41 = 0x3f4496b0 __NSDate
>   (lldb) p (int)[[[newTaskDict allKeys] lastObject] isEqualToDate:when]
>   (int) $42 = 0
>   (lldb) p (int)[[[newTaskDict allKeys] lastObject] hash]
>   (int) $43 = 358463317
>   (lldb) p (int)[when hash]
>   (int) $44 = 358463317

As you can see, `newTaskDict` has only one entry keyed by the original `NSDate` whose value is($38):
`0x0f8b5ff0 2012-05-11 21:08:37 +0000`
and whose hash is($43):
`35846331`

The other `NSDate` I used to retrieve the entry is($34):
`0x0f8be100 2012-05-11 21:08:37 +0000`
and its hash is($44):
`358463317`

Aren't these two `NSDate` exactly the same except for their memory addresses? How could `isEqual:`($39) and `isEqualToDate:`($42) return NO for them?

Solved:
This odd unequelness turned out to be caused by `sub-second differences`. You must read my second comment under the accepted answer because it is really interesting and it might bite you someday if you don't know it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isEqualToDate:` will also look at the milliseconds, which you cannot see by logging the object since the description method of `NSDate` only formats a human friendly string, however there is more information behind the date object.

It would seem your two dates are slightly different, this can happen even if they were created on the same run loop, try to create one and use just one object in 2 references, and then a second test to check two `NSDate` objects created separately - even one after the other, they should not be equal.

to Quote Apple documentation:

> This method detects sub-second differences between dates. If you want to compare dates with a less fine granularity, use timeIntervalSinceDate: to compare the two dates.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: 1) It is a specific time value, not a "now time" gotten from `[NSDate date]`. 2) As you can see I'm using `NSDate` as a dict key, so only `isEqual:` is meaningful for me. I can not "use timeIntervalSinceDate: to compare the two dates". 3) Sadly, I've lost that specific `NSDate` and now I can not repeat the odd unequalness.

Comment: As the documentation says it also takes into account "sub-second differences between dates" this would include but wouldn't be restricted to milliseconds.

Comment: After an experiment, I can say that it is must be the `sub-second differences` that caused this odd unequalness. Even though the two `NSDate` are expected to be of the same specific time value, the later one is returned back from the server. I guess there is some loss of precision in `sub-second` when the server stores the `NSDate`. The whole thing seems odder because two `NSDate`s return the same hash even though they carries different sub-second values.

Answer (score 1):

isEqual to date compares down to the microseconds. If you need less precision, use timeIntervalSinceDate: to test for the dates being within a range of microseconds, seconds, hours, days etc, of each other.

isEqual often uses the memory address itself to decide if its the same object, since if they have different addresses they are separate objects.